# I am trying to convert @forward to @use. My sass is not compiling properly?

Tags: css, sass, compilation

I am following Jonas Schmedtmann's Udemy Course on Advanced CSS & Sass. I am on section 5, lecture 32 and attempting to create a 7-1 Sass architecture. Jonas's tutorial is a bit outdated and uses @import, which is no longer supported.

I've tried to convert his code to how it would be using @use & @forward, but I cannot get it to compile properly.

I have index.scss files in each folder with the appropriate @forward tags. I appropriately reference files with @use. I believe it is either a reference error or an error with the specific layout folder.

Will someone review my sass code to see why it is not compiling properly? Here is my github repository. Thanks.

https://github.com/ruinedturnip/Natours_help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`@use` and `@forward` are only supported by **Dart Sass** and you're using **Node Sass** in your project, [which is deprecated](https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated). You need to replace `node-sass` with `sass` in your `package.json`.